# .dat file how to Encryption and decryption?

Tags: decryption, encryption

I am trying to decrypt or unpack a .dat file

I used a variety of methods, but do not work

When opened in notepad the text would look like these:

> ```
> luRd+WbiiNGDNgs3XLX1fA==
> vtAQlLx3N6HybkYYif3pAg==
> vtAQlLx3N6HybkYYif3pAg==
> 9JdxXwwekody7R71sJfnNg==
> Uc2tKVnaE9D7i9a7I5mkSg==
> no/LjqdIt463AtcpQ3HsNQ==
> y8edTmrN2DasIp5AbRhSUA==
> TXAti7Yp0C9B2bK7UGJ2Dw==
> CFIITpQZwsSoM9ZRz4x7IQ==
> tqDfa0PwuuhGTZ2QHHAZCw==
> uzxYGNWfX7JqeC+1n0Pq5A==
> 0sU/IzBFJMa9xkZhj8nIUQ==
> 2dGY80seATuhk6O4+Alrkw==
> MVoF0e786ixjif16qPv6VA==
> pqj/HI3lDFP2VleCCIMUdA==
> UdsYwz9HtyLMsBUz9iyMPg==
> AVN3BgbF2qXd1YfVEFtxVg==
> oCV8hqcsLQ3EEeXpLtxCIg==
> /YZ7shCsYom8ZQ7/B0gcdQ==
> Z5ST8wcMKhoJ9RuSUwW9aQ==
> 0lXdME9JNBM4TCx7woZEmQ==
> AVN3BgbF2qXd1YfVEFtxVg==
> oCV8hqcsLQ3EEeXpLtxCIg==
> /YZ7shCsYom8ZQ7/B0gcdQ==
> Z5ST8wcMKhoJ9RuSUwW9aQ==
> 0lXdME9JNBM4TCx7woZEmQ==
> 0lXdME9JNBM4TCx7woZEmQ==
> 5OeHvEhFCCVmhxCJziWlTw==
> CfT8HqIeXvgmcG3v5lZFWA==
> dNENzvuEtRQZ2JBSCfxf7Q==
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This is base64-encoded data, however data underneath it is unintelligible without further reverse engineering. How about reading the code that parses that data? an entry point could easily be base64 decoding/encoding functions